# How to find what ctrl+alt+up/down is mapped to?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac, shortcut

I have a MacBook Pro 2015.

I want ctrl+alt+up/down to map to duplicate line above/below in Intellij, but it is intercepted by macOS and causes the window to maximize to top/bottom of the screen.

I can't find where that mapping is in the keyboard shortcuts.

Does anyone know how to remove the mapping from macOS?

Comment: What version of macOS (or OS X, etc.) is on your MacBook?  In a comment on an answer you mention the system default.   It doesn't seem to be the system default on the first computer I tried, with OS X El Capitan 10.11.6.

Comment: I've found a solution: I previously used Karabiner to map CONTROL_L to COMMAND_L, and it caused this problem (so the actual Mac shortcut is command + alt + up/down).  Then I noticed Karabiner has a mapping for PC users, which only maps CONTROL_L to COMMAND_L in certain key combinations.  This solved the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All native macOS shortcuts are mapped through **Settings > Keyboard > Shortcuts**

You can search through all the lists and look for the following combination in the right hand column: `⌃⌥↑`. When you find it, you can either disable the checkbox in the far left or change the shortcut by double clicking it and entering a new shortcut.

You should now be able to use that shortcut in any program that the developer has mapped that for.

Comment: @Tetsujin Sorry, but I'm not sure what you're saying... I'm suggesting remapping the system default ⌃⌥↑ shortcut, then using the app as the developer intended.

Comment: Actually, I've found a way out: Karabiner has a mapping for PC users, and I just used it to remap the keys.  It is working fine now.

Comment: Thanks @stackoverflower and may I edit the answer to mention the possible Karabiner solution?

Comment: @DAVincent yep please feel free